# Proof the linear dependence of square singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the proof that a square matrix $A_{n×n}$ has $0$ determinant($det(A)=0$) if and only if a column is linear combination of the other columns?

From the usual Euclidean vector space equiped with real number field, this is easy to prove for real matrix. But I am seeking for some general proof for matrix with its entries being any scalar field $F$.

Comment: Do you know that $\mathrm{det}$ is a multilinear and alternating function?

Comment: What is your definition of "singular"?  That the determinant is zero? That $A$ has no inverse?

Comment: Also, what step would you use in the real-number case that can't be applied more generally?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to say determinant 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One direction:
Suppose that a column is a linear combination of the other columns.
WLOG, assume that this column is $C_1$. Then, you know that $C_1 = a_2C_2 + \cdots + a_nC_n$ for some suitable scalars $a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n$.
On the other hand, we know that elementary column operation $C_1 \mapsto C_1 - a_2C_2 - \cdots a_nC_n$ preserves the determinant. However, after this transformation, the first column is $[0\;0\;\cdots 0]^T$ and thus, the determinant is $0$.

Other direction:
Suppose that no column can be written as a linear combination of the other columns. This tells us that the $n$ columns are linearly independent. Thus, the $n$ columns form a basis of $F^n$.
In this view, it can be seen that $A$ is a bijective linear transform from $F^n$ to $F^n$.
Now, consider the inverse of this linear transform. By properties of linear transformations, this too will be linear. Consider the matrix representation $B$ of this linear transform.
It follows that $AB = BA = I$ and thus, the matrix $A$ is invertible and hence, non-singular.

Comment: No. I was trying to prove that what you have used, in the later part.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what part you want me to elaborate on?

Comment: I just want to prove the determinant is $0$. That is not the prove you have given. Because what I have I asked shall prove yourself.

Comment: @AlapanDas to prove that the determinant is non-zero, it suffices to note that
$$
1 = \det(I) = \det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)
$$

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $A$ is singular iff $\exists x \neq 0$ such that $Ax=0$. So,
$$Ax = A_1x_1 + \dots + A_nx_n = 0$$
where $A_i$ is $i$th column of $A$ and $x_i$ is $i$th element of $x$, which is equivalent to columns of $A$ being linearly dependent (again by definition).